# How to autowire factorybean instance (not the getObject() object) with annotations?

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

I know it is possible to get the reference to the factorybean instance when defining the beans with XML ([Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension)). e.g.:

```
<property name="factoryBean" ref="&amp;theFactoryBean" />
```

But is this also posible to do this with annotations? (maybe with @Autowired and @Qualifer?)

Do you have to annotate the factorybean itself to be discovered by Spring component-scan?

Comment: This was always a dubious practice; there's usually a better way of designing things, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your bean implement `BeanFactoryAware`, but as skaffman says, it's not a great practice.